# c++ non-comprehensible crashing behaviour

Tags: c++, crash

So I created this dll today and it's crashing for no reason...

**This works:**

```
testa++;
testb++;

const char *t = "test";

if (t == "adoinfosidnoxucnviune")
{
}
```

**This crashes at testb++:**

```
testa++;

const char *t = "test";

if (t == "adoinfosidnoxucnviune")
{
    testb++;
}
```

Where testa and testb are integers..
t isnt even the string it's compared with, I don't get it

Comment: You can't compare C strings like that.

Comment: the exact same thing happens with strcmp(t,"whatever")==0

Comment: Complete example please. Is `testb` initialized?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if there's UB in code you haven't shown.

Comment: What is testb, what is testa? How do you declare them, how do you initialize them? Not enough info

Comment: Also, how it can crash at testb++, if condition (t == "adoinfosidnoxucnviune") can't be true? testb++ even doesn't execute

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing pointers, not the values the pointers point to.

Either use `strcmp` or use `std::string`.

The crash has to occur elsewhere.

Because you are pointing to two different objects, the code in either "if" statement is not executed because the values in the pointers are different.

Somewhere in your code, you are testing the value of `testb`.  In the first example, `testb` is always incremented.  In the second example, `testb` is not incremented.

Have you initialized `testb`?

Seriously, when you single stepped with the debugger, what was the last line executed before the crash?

Comment: Why would the first example not crash then?

Comment: Comparing valid pointers is perfectly okay(even if it doesn't produce the desired behavior), and should never cause a crash.

Comment: I didn't state that comparing pointers was the cause of the crash.  It may cause problems later in the code.

Comment: Both testa and testb are initialized with value 0. I cannot single step with the debugger, because it's a dll that is used as a plugin in another application of mine, or can I? If i take testb++ out of the if block, it works